Can't activate jar-dependencies-0.3.10, already activated jar-dependencies-0.4.1
I'm getting this error.
can't activate jar-dependencies-0.3.10, already activated jar-dependencies-0.4.1

Please help me
My project has gem 'jar-dependencies', '0.4.1' but in my system it was different. I tried to update and changed the default one. It started showing that error.
